# How can you provide translations (localization) for attributes and properties in the icCube schema definition?

Tags: localization, iccube

In the **icCube - Builder**, defining a database schema:

How can you provide localizations for **attribute members** and **properties** of members in the Schema Builder. When generating a template, these are excluded in the download file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute members are localized like regular hierarchies. They should be in the localization export.

For properties, these fields cannot be localized. To localize them, you'll first need to create a measure from the property. This measure you can then localize.

This is for example how to create a measure from a property on the Geography hierarchy.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Lattitude] as [Geography].[Geography].currentMember.getProperty("@Ic3Lat",TYPED), CAPTION="@Ic3Lat"
```